# Can't see derived output of scripting tool in ModelBuilder, Add Surface Information does not work as expected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, 3d-analyst

The [add surface information](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/add-surface-information.htm) tool in ArcGIS 10 (3D Analyst Tool) does not work correctly.  The input parameter for scaling the data  are set to 1 but after code execution the results are always multipled 3.28083.  If you run the tool as a stand-alone script in an IDE is works as promised.  In response I decided I should make my own scripting tool to correct this problem.  I cannot make this scripting tool work correctly.

Add surface information does not have a formal output since it only adds a new column to the attribute table.   I would like to use the tool in a model builder model but there needs to have an output to link the process to other tools.  Based on my reading of tools with no output this scripting tool should have a derived output so that it can be linked with other tools in a model.  I have looked at [Obtained from](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm#GUID-E4CF478D-D449-4A65-A77C-74A424FD0AF6) help, and code examples at [Problem with output paramater in script tool - Does not work in model builder!](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/problem-with-output-paramater-in-script-tool-does/m-p/731385) but I cannot see the output when I add my scripting tool to ModelBuilder.

Here is a screen shot from a ModelBuilder model.  The top add surface information tool from the 3D analyst includes an output feature class that can be used to link to other tools.  The lower add surface information does not have the output feature class and I cannot link my tool to other processes without getting an error.

[image]

Here are my input parameters to the scripting tool for the final derived output.

[image]

I have included the code below.

How to I get a derived output in an ArcGIS 10 model builder model?

```
in_fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_ras = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
out_property = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
method = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
sampling_distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
z_factor = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
pyramid_level_resolution = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
noise_filtering = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)

arcpy.SetParameterAsText(8, in_fc)    

arcpy.AddSurfaceInformation_3d(in_fc, in_ras, out_property, method, sampling_distance, z_factor, pyramid_level_resolution, noise_filtering)
```

Comment: 3.28 is conversion from meters to feet. Just sort out your units.

Comment: I understand the 3.28 value, the problem is it does this scaling even when both the surface model and the raster data are using State Plane (feet ) coordinates.  I do not want to have to remember to reduce my output values by then having to multiply the resulting outputs by 0.3048 thus the new model.

Comment: Ah, I see that it does not do this 3.28 with data that is in UTM meters.  Strange that the tool would behave differently with CRS.